# SQL Filter values depending on other values from the same column

Tags: sql, impala

I have a database that has Time, Action and Value columns. I want to filter certain Actions depending on other Actions.
Example:

```
Time    Action              Value
1:30    Drink sold          5
1:31    Happy hour          1
1:32    Drink sold          5 *
1:33    Happy hour          1
1:34    Drink sold          5 *
1:35    Drink sold          5 *
1:36    Drink sold          5 *
1:37    Happy hour          0
1:38    Drink sold          5
1:39    Drink sold          5
1:40    Drink sold          5
1:41    Happy hour          0
1:42    Drink sold          5
1:43    Happy hour          1
1:44    Drink sold          5 *
1:45    Happy hour          1
1:46    Drink sold          5 *
1:47    Drink sold          5 *
1:48    Drink sold          5 *
1:49    Happy hour          0
1:50    Drink sold          5
```

The result should only contain the drinks sold while Happy hour is 1. Marked with *. Happy hour can be set repeatedly.
The database is [impala](/questions/tagged/impala) but ideally a solution just uses plain SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses `lag()` to compare the most recent rows with happy hour records.  Then just consider where the most recent has a value of "1":

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when action = 'Happy hour' and value = 0 then time end) over (order by time) as happy_hour_0,
             max(case when action = 'Happy hour' and value = 1 then time end) over (order by time) as happy_hour_1
      from t
     ) t
where action = 'Drink sold' and
      ((happy_hour_0 is null and happy_hour_1 is not null) or
       (happy_hour_1 > happy_hour_0)
      );
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!
Only change: AS t